# Reading either byte[] or float with Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have table with one column being binary and another being float. I need to select the following using SQL

```
SELECT ISNULL(myBinary, myFloat) FROM table
```

That works and I get one column with all binary

```
0x3F800000
0xE5C13DBAB611123B47A7
0x9946C3BA9946C3BA9946
0xDE0E1D3C8B7A143C6DB7
0x3F800000
```

etc.

Now I would like to make this query using Linq to Entities, however I just can't find a code that would compile

```
context.table.select(s => new MyObject()
  { 
     Result = s.myBinary ?? s.myFloat // <--- '??' operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'float'
  });

 class MyObject { public Object Result {get; set;} }
```

How do I get those values? BitConverter doesn't work either (on the float)

**UPDATE**

Why I'm asking: so if I were to select both columns seperately, I get more execution time

```
set statistics time on
SELECT TOP (5000) ISNULL([x], [y])
  FROM [table];
set statistics time off
set statistics time on
SELECT TOP (5000) [x], [y]
  FROM [table];
  set statistics time off
```

yields (even executing it multiple time, it's always around the same)

```
(5000 rows affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 7 ms.

(5000 rows affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 113 ms.
```

Note: In one comment I wrote factor 40, that was with another measurement method. The statistics time yields about factor 10.

If I increase the amount of rows, I get

```
(50000 rows affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 47 ms,  elapsed time = 820 ms. (with ISNULL)

(50000 rows affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 16 ms,  elapsed time = 1365 ms.
```

and with less rows (about 1000 or less), the execution time is not measurable equally, so about 1 ms. BUT: I expect about presicely 5000 to 10000 rows per query.

Comment: Try casting maybe?  e.g. `Result = (object)s.myBinary ?? (object)s.myFloat`.  I agree with DavidG - you probably shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: How would you expect your app to deal with a `float` *or* a `byte[]`? You're left with horrible things like reflection. Why not just return both values and use the binary column unless it's null?

Comment: Hm... I get *Unable to cast the type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.*

Comment: @DavidG There's an issue with performance. Reading both creates atm too much traffic. The float value is read always and always not null. But I need that only in case the binary entry is null.

Comment: Possible solution: create a view that does the `SELECT ISNULL(myBinary, myFloat) FROM table` and map it to EF

Comment: Did you try a computed column?

Comment: Also, does the execution time depend on the number of null values in the first column?

Comment: @GertArnold Probably, I didn't check that. Just visualy looking at the data, I'd say it's somewhere around 50% null values in the first column.

Comment: EF6 or ? Code first model or edmx?

Comment: @IvanStoev EF6 and edmx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I can offer as solution is a custom store function, mapped to the built-in `ISNULL` SQL function.

If you were using Code First model, you would need 
[EntityFramework.Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986217/reading-either-byte-or-float-with-linq-to-entities) package.

But since you are using edmx, the process is a bit more complicated and requires manual editing of the edmx file. The technique is partially covered by the [How to: Define Custom Functions in the Storage Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296754) MSDN topic.

Open your edmx file with XML (text) editor. Locate the `Schema` sub element of the `edmx:StorageModels` element and add the following inside:

```
<Function Name="IsNull" BuiltIn="true" IsComposable="true" ReturnType="binary">
  <Parameter Name="expr1" Type="binary" />
  <Parameter Name="expr2" Type="float" />
</Function>
```

Note that as mentioned in the MSDN link:

> Changes made to the SSDL section of an .edmx file, as suggested in the procedure below, will be overwritten if you use the Update Model Wizard to update your model.

so make sure to keep this in some safe place and re-include it if you update the edmx from the database.

Then add a method in some static class and decorate it with the `DbFunction` attribute:

```
public static class CustomDbFunctions
{
    const string Namespace = "EFTest.MyDbContextModel.Store";

    [DbFunction(Namespace, "IsNull")]
    public static byte[] IsNull(byte[] expr1, double expr2) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

(update the `Namespace` string to match the value of the `Namespace` attribute of the `<edmx:StorageModels><Schema>` element).

And that's all. Now you should be able to use the above function in your LINQ to Entities queries:

```
class MyObject { public byte[] Result { get; set;} }

context.MyTable.Select(e => new MyObject
{ 
    Result = CustomDbFunctions.IsNull(e.myBinary, e.myFloat)
});
```

and EF6 will happily translate it to the desired SQL `ISNULL` function.

Comment: I tested it, and it appers to work very well... Give me some hours, I'll double check it with the real production data

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the way you are trying to get this to work is that you would need to resort to some nasty hacks to determine if your return value was a `byte[]` or a `float`. That's why you've been trying to get the EF query to return `object`. It may be possible to get it working by hacking the `float` into a `byte[]`, but I would suggest a far simpler and more logical approach: Return both values and let the app decide what to do. For example, return something like this object:

```
public class FloatOrByte // Do not call it this!
{
    public byte[] MyBinary { get; set; }
    public float MyFloat { get; set; }
}
```

And return it like this:

```
var result = context.table.Select(s => new FloatOrByte
{ 
    MyBinary = s.myBinary,
    MyFloat = s.myFloat
};
```

Now you can check the value for null:

```
if(result.MyBinary != null)
{
    // Do stuff with the byte value
}
else
{
    // Do stuff with the float value
}
```

Comment: Yes I have that now implemented, but that makes the code too slow. Executing the SQL as in the op is clearly quicker than returning both columns.

Comment: Is there **really** a perf issue? Granted, it's not perfect, but I doubt returning a single float value that isn't always needed is going to affect your app, particularly when you are returning a `byte[]` that could be massive.

Comment: Well, I can't really tell since I did not make the code work yet. However only working in SQL Server Manager I get a perf. boost using the OP SQL. And yes, right now it's too slow for the customer.

Comment: How can you tell there's a perf boost by using SQL Server Manager? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Scope the time to execute one SQL query vs. the time to execute another SQL query.

Comment: And the difference in execution times is? Did you run it enough times to get a good baseline? Does the improvement in the query give you any tangible benefit in your app?

Comment: Eric Lippert explains this better than me... https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Executing both codes, i.e. once with `ISNULL(x, y)` and once with `SELECT x, y` gives me an average time difference (about 1000 executions per query) of approx. 40x, i.e. the isnull query is about 40 times faster. That alone on SQL level. Now the performance difference on LINQ level I cannot tell. That's why I asked the question. But right now I have *double* the amout of data to process server side when there is apparantly a solution SQL side...

Comment: I am stunned (to the point where I kind of don't believe it) that you claim a 40x speed increase by using a query that does *more work* as it has to call `ISNULL` and convert the float value to varbinary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173619/discussion-between-rst-and-davidg).

Answer (score 0):

Please change your class definition to accept null values.

```
public class FloatOrByte 
{
    public byte[] MyBinary { get; set; }
    public float? MyFloat { get; set; }
}
```

Then fetch values using your DBContext class. The problem is EF can't translate the null-coalescing operator to SQL.

```
var result = context.table.Select(s => s);

var processResult = result.Tolist().Select(s=> new MyObject{

    Result = (s.MyBinary == null) ? (object)s.MyFloat : (object)s.MyBinary 

 });
```

Comment: Quote: *Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'float'*

Comment: Please read the comments of the OP: "Unable to cast the type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.Object'"

Comment: Any type can be cast to Object type even user defined type. I hope you have class MyObject with  "Result"  property as Object type ,it is working perfectly in my code . Please try

Comment: Wrong error message: *Unable to cast the type 'System.Single' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.*